# UISlider on UITableViewCell only responsive above certain part of screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

This problem only occurs on iPhone 4S as the 5S and 6 have enough screen height that the problem doesn't affect the app.

In the screenshot, the UISlider does not respond to touch in an area from roughly where the slider is to the base of the screen (the cyan arrow).

Scroll the table up and the slider responds fine.

The table is responsive to up/down scrolling anywhere on the screen. 
Scroll the row with the slider down and it stops responding to touch in the 'cyan arrow' area.

[image]

De-queuing code is:

```
BrightnessTableViewCell * cell = [tableViewIn dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BrightnessTableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[BrightnessTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"BrightnessTableViewCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
```

nib registration in viewDidLoad

```
   UINib *nib2 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BrightnessTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
[[self tableView] registerNib:nib2 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BrightnessTableViewCell"];
```

Comment: Ignore the activity indicators, they are just in a debug mode

Comment: Could you add the code you use to dequeue cells in your table view?

Answer (score 0):

And it was...

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return 200;
}
```

I put that there to solve another issue where the last separator is white despite setting a custom colour (that works for all other separator lines).

Anyway, changing the height above to 20 cured the issue.